# jQuery - I need a limiter for my slider

Tags: jquery, slideshow

you can see my start with jquery == > [here](http://nbvfx.net/_test_js/)

I've made a simple slideshow with vimeo-videos. If you click on the Arrows up/down my `<ul>`-List move up and down. But how can I STOP moving, if the last Video (`<li><</li>`) has arrived. I need an If/else condition, but I don't know how ..

Sth. like that, if my last `<li>` arrived, stop add 80px and return.false() ..

I have these slideshow several times at my page, sometimes I have 2 Videos, 3, 4 or 15 .. so I need an universal solution ..

Comment: just looking at your code, you might benefit from using jQuery's offset() function

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('ul li').last()){
  $(this).stop().animate({'margin-top':'80px'}, function(){
    return false;
  });

}else{
  // all other list items. 
  // Normal stuff here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling by 80px is probably not the way I would do it, but using your method, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// vimeo videos
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mediagallery").mediaGallery({autoplay:1});

// scroll action
$('#mediagallery_down').click(function() {
    var pos = $('#med_list_cont').css("top").replace("px", "");
    if (pos <= 0 )
        $('#med_list_cont').css("top", parseFloat(pos) + -80 +"px");
});

$('#mediagallery_up').click(function() {
    var pos = $('#med_list_cont').css("top").replace("px", "");
    if (pos >= ($('#med_list_cont').height() - $('#mediagallery_list').height()))
    {
        $('#med_list_cont').css("top", parseFloat(pos) + 80 +"px");
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah offset(); that was the hint I needed. Thank you

```
jQuery('#mediagallery_down').click(function() {

     if(jQuery('#med_list_cont li:last').offset().top <= 790)
                    jQuery(this).fadeOut('fast');
    var pos = jQuery('#med_list_cont').css("top").replace("px", "");
    jQuery('#med_list_cont').css("top", parseFloat(pos) + -80 +"px");

});

jQuery('#mediagallery_up').click(function() {
        jQuery('#mediagallery_down').show();
 if(jQuery('#med_list_cont li:first').offset().top >= 464)
               return false;    

var pos = jQuery('#med_list_cont').css("top").replace("px", "");
    jQuery('#med_list_cont').css("top", parseFloat(pos) + 80 +"px");

});
```